# Как сделать необязательным поле с типом DecimalField в форме Джанго

Tags: django, django-orm, django-model, field

В форме Джанго мне нужно сделать необязательным поле с типом DecimalField().

Поле: price = forms.DecimalField().

Пробовала писать price = forms.DecimalField(blank=True, null=True), но сервер выдает ошибку:
****init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'blank'**.

Как быть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

чтобы сделать его не обьязательным нужно вот так

```
price = forms.DecimalField(required=False)
```

читайте здесь https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/fields/#decimalfield

Comment: Большое спасибо, буду знать!